# How to remove an entry with alphanumerical value in the HashMap using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I have a HashMap with Key and Values. All the keys and values are of the String type coming from sensors. For example

```
map = {
temperature: "35.6",
pressure: "1012",
station_type: "FM-17"
.
.
.
}
```

Now, I want to remove keys from the map that contain alphanumerical values from my map in this case, station_type and only keep temperature and pressure.

I tried it using regex, but it is not working. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in the below code?

```
for(String m:keyValueRecord.keySet()){
   if(keyValueRecord.get(m).matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]")){
      keyValueRecord.remove(m);
}
}
```

Also, is there any other way I can do that without using regex?

Comment: Use `if(m.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")`. You're matching no the `value` not the `key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood question correctly you want to remove the entry if the value has alphanumeric.for example

**Input:**
`{temperature=35.6, pressure=1012, station_type=FM17, station_type3=FM-@17, station_type2=fm, station_type1=FM}`

**Expected Output:**
`{temperature=35.6, pressure=1012, station_type2=fm, station_type1=FM}`

```java
   String onlyNumbers = "^[0-9.]*$";
        String onlyAlphabets = "[a-zA-Z]*$";
        final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
            if (!entry.getValue().matches(onlyNumbers)&&!entry.getValue().matches(onlyAlphabets)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

or Java8

```java
  map.entrySet().removeIf(entry->!entry.getValue().matches(onlyNumbers)&&!entry.getValue().matches(onlyAlphabets));
```

Comment: Ok that works well for alphanumeric, but what if I also want to remove station_type2 and station_type1? To make it more tricky, what would be the common regex for dealing with all the cases i.e. alphanumeric, only alphabets, only numbers, numbers with special characters and alphabets with special characters?

Comment: @tank my answer will only fulfill the question which is posted here. If you want to remove station_type2 and station_type1 then you can remove the only alphabets check then you will get only temperature and pressure values. If that is the right answer means you're checking for only numbers.

Comment: @tank if you want "only alphabets or only numbers or numbers with special characters or alphabets with special characters" you can use **"[0-9.]*|[a-zA-Z]*|[^a-zA-Z]*|[^0-9.]*"**.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the regex, **it's not valid to modify the map while iterating over its keyset in this way.** It may throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` or produce an undefined result.

In order to remove elements while iterating over a map, you need to use iterator explicitly.

```
final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = keyValueRecord.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
    if (entry.getValue().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Or you could use the Java 8 way:

```
map.values().removeIf(value -> value.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*"));
```

Comment: This expression remove all other entries except the station_type. When I modified a little bit, it works well map.values().removeIf(value->!value.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$") );

Answer (score 1):

I believe `removeIf` can be an option here on the `keySet`

```
keyValueRecord.keySet().removeIf(k -> keyValueRecord.get(k).matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]`

that matches **one** a-Z,0-9 char. Did you mean `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead to match 1 or more?!

Answer (score 0):

With Java8 you can write it in the following way:

```
keyValueRecord.entrySet().stream()
 .filter((k, v) -> k.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
 .collect(toMap(MapEntry::getKey, MapEntry::getEntry))
```

Comment: This will create a new map, not modify the existing one.